# Guards attacking on sight in Nashkel

Tags: baldurs-gate-enhanced

I have a problem: the guards in Nashkel attack me on sight, even though my Reputation is 13, and it says that I am Popular (my character is a Chaotic Evil Half-Orc).

I think it might have something to do with something that happened at the start of the game, when I tried to force open a lock, and someone saw me; I killed the guard, and now I'm hanging around wearing his armor and stuff, but I have been a good boy since then.
Is this some kind of bug? Should I restart the game?

EDIT: I donated 1.5k gold to the temple next to the Friendly Arm Inn, my reputation increased to 14, I went back to Nashkel, and I'm still being attacked by the guards. Is this because I'm playing a Chaotic Evil character?

Comment: Is this the original release or ee?

Comment: @Studoku It is EE

Comment: Where were you when you killed the guard?

Comment: @Mark Candlekeep, I was just starting the game

Comment: Were the guards attacking you Nashkel guards (who can be bribed), or Flaming Fist soldiers?

Comment: @Joachim The guards at Nashkel, they don't even talk to me, they attack me as soon as I arrive. I had to start a new game to be able to get there.

Comment: You’re wearing guard armour? What happens if you take it off and wear something different instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it might have something to do with...

Exactly.

The fact that Flaming Fist soldiers will spawn and attack you at very low reputations (much lower than 13 - i think less than 5) has nothing to do with this.

Once you make someone hostile, (even a Nashkel guard), they will stay there and be hostile forever. You made them hostile once, there's no way to un-hostile them, even if you get reputation 20.

Comment: Thanks man. After two years of trying to get an answer for this, you finally gave me one. So, I guess there's no need for trying to be nice anymore. I had to drop that save, but it is still there